# How can I use JavaScript to open a new browser tab with a specified title?

Tags: javascript, html

"I'm working on a JavaScript project and I need to open a new browser tab with a specific title using JavaScript. I've tried searching online but couldn't find a solution that meets my requirements.

I need to set the title dynamically based on certain variables or user input. Any help or guidance, including code examples or recommended JavaScript methods, would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!"

Comment: @NehaSoni may be you are right

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if its got anything to do with your single quotes but try changing that or vs versa. Try the following if that fails.

```
newTab.document.title = "wo_print";
```

Comment: newTab.document.title = "wo_print" - not working

Comment: I'm not sure if it matter but what browser are you using and what device are you testing this one?

Comment: chrome and hp device

Answer (score 0):

```
function OpenWindow() {
        var myWindow = window.open('YourURL.html','myWindow','resizable,scrollbars');
        myWindow.document.write('<title>Windows Title</title><body><h1>Your html content</h1></body>');
}




<a style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="OpenWindow()">Open in New Window</a>
```

Comment: I can't send myWindow.document.write('<title>This is New Title</title>'); this way.. mywindow.document.write ( here i send whole html code send ) , the whole html code doesn't have title

Comment: I updated my code, check out it.

Comment: my html code contain <title></title>, I can't add manually, I need alternate option

Answer (score 0):

```
let newTab = window.open('www.google.com')
newTab.onload = function () {
  newTab.document.title = menu.menuName
}
```

Comment: newTab.onload = function () {
  newTab.document.title = menu.menuName
} - NOT WORK

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include a explanation. Code only answers are less useful to OP and future readers.

Comment: ’menu. MenuName ‘ should be a string，let newTab = window.open('www.google.com')
newTab.onload = function () {
  newTab.document.title = "custom tabName"
}